# pip isn't working today and all it's modules

Tags: python, cmd, pip

pip was working with me and all it's modules but after i was testing new methods in my code pychram stopped and lagged, so i restarted my laptop and now pip isn't working nor it's modules , like tweepy

This is what the computer tell me when i write pip in the cmd

```
File "c:\users\goldenworld\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 14, in <mo               dule>
    import importlib.machinery # importlib first so we can test #15386 via -m
File "c:\users\goldenworld\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", li               ne 57, in <module>
    import types
File "c:\users\goldenworld\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\types.py", line 171, in <m               odule>
    import functools as _functools
File "c:\users\goldenworld\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\functools.py", line 21, in                <module>
    from collections import namedtuple
File "c:\users\goldenworld\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\collections\__init__.py",                line 135
    'od.__iter__() <==> iter(od)
                               ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

I was using the method `__iter__()`, 
even tkinter package isn't working.

Comment: That looks like you manually screwed with standard library files. Don't do that. You probably have to reinstall Python now.

Comment: "pip isn't working today", so try again tomorrow!

Comment: should i remove python then reinstall it or reinstall it while it exists

Comment: I'd uninstall and reinstall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have done there is totally messed the program and specifically python, I have not used pip but considering what you have done try this:

1. Re-Install the program.
2. Re-Install python.
3. Never attempt that again.